# Sections being indented for no reason

Tags: indentation

I'm trying to draft a resume and I used [this](https://github.com/arasgungore/arasgungore-CV/blob/main/main.tex) template. However, as you notice, there is indentation of each section heading for no reason:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. I tried disabling indentation globally but it did not work too.

Here is the shorter version of the code:

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Aras Gungore
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\makeatletter
% This command ignores the optional argument for itemize and enumerate lists
\newcommand{\inlineitem}[1][]{%
\ifnum\enit@type=\tw@
    {\descriptionlabel{#1}}
  \hspace{\labelsep}%
\else
  \ifnum\enit@type=\z@
       \refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
    \quad\@itemlabel\hspace{\labelsep}%
\fi}
\makeatother
\parindent=0pt


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands

\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeEducationHeading}[6]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
      \textit{\small#5} & \textit{\small #6} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}


\newcommand{\resumeOrganizationHeading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
      \textit{\small#3}
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

\begin{document}

%---------- HEADING ----------

\begin{center}
   ...
   ...
   ...

%----------- EDUCATION -----------

\section{Education}
 ...
 ...
 ...
 
%----------- SKILLS -----------

\section{Skills}
  \vspace{2pt}
...
...
...

%----------- EXPERIENCE -----------

\section{Experience}
...
...
...

%----------- PROJECTS -----------
\section{Projects}
...
...
...

\section{Awards}
  \vspace{2pt}
...
...
...

\section{Others}
  \vspace{2pt}
...
...
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch I have added a short version. The full code can be found on the github site. Please let me know if you need more details!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: however even with that error all the headings are aligned [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3E18.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I accidentally removed the end center while removing some personal details. Is small causing all trouble? BTW I used overleaf to compile

Comment: no code you have shown so far is the cause of the problem as the document has all sections indented by the same amount. You need to post an example of the problem. post the image generated by the code that you post, not from a different document.